# cannot start pgadmin4 python app

Tags: python-3.x, pgadmin

I am missing something, I have downloaded pgadmin4 webapp, and trying to launch it in its environnement:

```
(pgadmin) denis ~/anaconda3/envs/pgadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pgadmin4 $ pip install flask_babel
Requirement already satisfied: flask_babel in /home/denis/anaconda3/envs/pgadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.5 in /home/denis/anaconda3/envs/pgadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from flask_babel)
Requirement already satisfied: Babel>=2.3 in /home/denis/anaconda3/envs/pgadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from flask_babel)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask in /home/denis/anaconda3/envs/pgadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from flask_babel)
Requirement already satisfied: markupsafe in /home/denis/anaconda3/envs/pgadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.5->flask_babel)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=0a in /home/denis/anaconda3/envs/pgadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from Babel>=2.3->flask_babel)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.21 in /home/denis/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from Flask->flask_babel)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.7 in /home/denis/anaconda3/envs/pgadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from Flask->flask_babel)
(pgadmin) denis ~/anaconda3/envs/pgadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pgadmin4 $ sudo python pgAdmin4.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pgAdmin4.py", line 34, in <module>
    import config
  File "/home/denis/anaconda3/envs/pgadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pgadmin4/config.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pgadmin.utils import env, IS_PY2, IS_WIN, fs_short_path
  File "/home/denis/anaconda3/envs/pgadmin/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from flask_babel import Babel, gettext
ImportError: No module named flask_babel
```

What can I do more than `source activate pgadmin` and install all `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Idk what the problem is but do you have postgres installed? Doesnt make much sense that that would create the flask_babel error but worth a shot.

Comment: yes I already have it. Just wanna have pgAdmin4, I have pgAdmin3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `sudo python` doesnt use your virtualenv. Install pgadmin reqs globally or drop sudo.

Comment: virtualenvs have their own python version (e.g. ~/.pyenv/versions). sudo python uses it in /usr/bin or whatever. (so reqs stored in ~/.pyenv are not loaded).

Comment: then why da hell packages want to create foldrs in /var, and why they ask to install a virtualenv ..; drives me crazy. Can't they just install in user space